# running an R script from another directory

Tags: r, rscript

Here's an example with a couple of scripts

```
test.R ==>
source("incl.R", chdir=TRUE)
print("test.R - main script")

incl.R ==>
print("incl.R - included")
```

They are both in the same directory.  When I run it from that directory using `Rscript --vanilla test.R`, it works fine.  I would like to create multiple subdirectories (run1, run2, run3, ...) and run my original scripts for different parameter values.  Suppose I `cd run1` and then try to run the script, I get

```
C:\Downloads\scripts\run1>Rscript --vanilla ..\test.R
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open the connection
Calls: source -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'incl.R': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that I unserstand your problem correctly. I assume that you have your scripts `test.R` and `incl.R` in the *same* folder and then run `test.R` using `Rscript` from some other folder. `test.R` should figure out where `test.R` (and thus `incl.R`) is stored and then source `incl.R`.

The trick is that you have to put the full path to the script `test.R` as an argument to your call of `Rscript`. It is possible to get this argument using `commandArgs` and then construct the path to `incl.R` from it:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=FALSE)
file.arg <- grep("--file=",args,value=TRUE)
incl.path <- gsub("--file=(.*)test.R","\\1incl.R",file.arg)
source(incl.path,chdir=TRUE)
```

In your example in the question, you call the script by `Rscript --vanilla ..\test.R`. `args` will then be a character vector that contains the element "--file=../test.R". With `grep` I grab this element and then use `gsub` to obtain the  path "../incl.R" from it. This path can then be used in `source`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  You did understand the question correctly.  Is there a way to not have the path hard coded ("../incl.R")?  Is it possible to programmatically obtain the path for test.R, and then add that path when sourcing the other scripts?

Comment: I reformulated the answer such that the path is not hard coded any longer.